# Unity2d shooting while running

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I shoot a projectile while running the projectile collides with the player, i.e. the player's collider is hitting the bullet's collider.

What is the best way to prevent this? By making a space between the gun and the projectile to avoid collision?

Comment: How ***did*** you make it? Show your code.

Comment: I think my question is very clear, how to avoid touching the projectile while shouting and running at the same time

Comment: SO is not a micro job platform "please write some code for me having those features".  You have to present reproducible code snippets where the problem probably occurs. Nobody can know why there is an unwanted collision in your approach. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) The question is on hold now. That means you have the chance to improve your question by editing (link below your Q) and, when done, may ask to reopen it.

Comment: If you upload a simple runnable demo project on any upload platform and provide a link here in the comments, people might help you to select relevant snippets to improve your question.

Comment: i just want to point out that this is a perfectly valid question. and if it was answerable i would tell you to go into your collision layers, and set the player object to not collide with the bullet object. its as simple as making sure they both are properly tagged, then unchecking the box that allows them to collide

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone this question dosnt need code, its a physics problem that is fixable with unity collision layers.

Comment: go into, edit-project settings, then tags.   add a layer for player, add a layer full bullet. go into your player and bullet objects, and in the inspector on the top right change the layer from default (put player on layer player, and bullet on layer bullet.)

Comment: no the hard work is done, so next go to edit-project settings- physics 2d. from there in the inspector there is a matrix of check marks, uncheck the box that crosses both player and bullet, and they will no longer collide with each other

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens thanks it works but when I colloid with enemy I lose my colloid  and the player across the ground platform and the player goes down (he lose the colloid with platform) that is happened after I did the uncheck the box that crosses both player and bullet I'm sure that I did as you said and I didn't uncheck the player with the ground platform any help

Comment: I avoid that by adding  the player to an empty game object and layer the player as player thank's very much if you add your text as answer I will make sure to check the answer mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can think of right now.

1- You can create a selective collision script (or edit your existing one) and add an exception for the player object. So, bullets can go through the player.  This is the main way to go.

2- You can use layers (or Z depth) and you can create a whole layer for bullet spawner etc. And make enemies also have targets in that layer/depth.

*I don't have Unity installed on my current system right now. But I will install it when I get a chance, and if you don't solve it until then I will try to help properly.*

Comment: the first one did you mean make  uncolloid  with the player how to do that any line of code plzz

Comment: these would work, but kind of redundant as unity uses the layer collision system for just this purpose. check out my comments above for the proper way to fix this problem. although, @bruce, both your answers are clever, and not wrong, just not right for unity